# Linq2SQL: Optimize query?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, query-optimization

Can I optimized the following query in any way:

The goal is to try to find clients of type 4 that also exists as type2 based on their VAT and Email. A client can have one or more clientusers.

(I have all the appropriate indexes set, I promise)

```
from e in Clients.Where(h => h.ClientTypeId==4)
 join u in ClientUsers on e.Id equals u.ClientId
 where
 e.DeleteFlag.Equals("n") &&
 (

     (!(e.VAT == null || e.VAT.Equals("")) && Clients.Any(f => f.ClientTypeId == 2 && f.VAT.Equals(e.VAT)))

     || (!(e.Email == null || e.Email.Equals("")) &&
         (
             Clients.Any(f => f.ClientTypeId == 2 && f.Email.ToLower().Equals(e.Email.ToLower()))
             || (from f in ClientUsers join q in Clients on f.ClientId equals q.Id where f.Email.Equals(e.Email.ToLower()) && q.ClientTypeId == 2 select f.Id).Any()
         )
     )

     || (!(u.Email == null || u.Email.Equals("")) &&
         (
             Clients.Any(f => f.ClientTypeId == 2 && f.Email.ToLower().Equals(u.Email.ToLower()))
             || (from f in ClientUsers join q in Clients on f.ClientId equals q.Id where f.Email.Equals(u.Email.ToLower()) && q.ClientTypeId == 2 select f.Id).Any()
         )
     )

 )
 select e
```

Results in:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1) SET @p0 = 'n'
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1) SET @p1 = ''
DECLARE @p2 Int SET @p2 = 2
DECLARE @p3 NVarChar(1) SET @p3 = ''
DECLARE @p4 Int SET @p4 = 2
DECLARE @p5 Int SET @p5 = 2
DECLARE @p6 NVarChar(1) SET @p6 = ''
DECLARE @p7 Int SET @p7 = 2
DECLARE @p8 Int SET @p8 = 2
DECLARE @p9 Int SET @p9 = 4
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[AccountId], [t0].[CompanyName], [t0].[Address], [t0].[Address2], [t0].[PostCode], [t0].[PostArea], [t0].[ContactPerson], [t0].[Phone], [t0].[Email], [t0].[VAT], [t0].[Webpage], [t0].[Description], [t0].[Active], [t0].[PreRegcode], [t0].[PreRegcheck], [t0].[AccountCreated], [t0].[UpdateTimeStamp], [t0].[DeleteFlag], [t0].[ClientTypeId], [t0].[CampaignCodeId], [t0].[PayexId], [t0].[ApiKey], [t0].[InvoiceName], [t0].[Source], [t0].[ProspectStatusId], [t0].[ProspectLastCommentId], [t0].[ProspectCallbackDate]
FROM [Clients] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [ClientUsers] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[Id]) = [t1].[ClientId]
WHERE ([t0].[DeleteFlag] = @p0) AND (((NOT (([t0].[VAT] IS NULL) OR ([t0].[VAT] = @p1))) AND (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Clients] AS [t2]
    WHERE ([t2].[ClientTypeId] = @p2) AND ([t2].[VAT] = [t0].[VAT])
    ))) OR ((NOT (([t0].[Email] IS NULL) OR ([t0].[Email] = @p3))) AND ((EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Clients] AS [t3]
    WHERE ([t3].[ClientTypeId] = @p4) AND (LOWER([t3].[Email]) = LOWER([t0].[Email]))
    )) OR (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [ClientUsers] AS [t4]
    INNER JOIN [Clients] AS [t5] ON [t4].[ClientId] = ([t5].[Id])
    WHERE ([t4].[Email] = LOWER([t0].[Email])) AND ([t5].[ClientTypeId] = @p5)
    )))) OR ((NOT (([t1].[Email] IS NULL) OR ([t1].[Email] = @p6))) AND ((EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Clients] AS [t6]
    WHERE ([t6].[ClientTypeId] = @p7) AND (LOWER([t6].[Email]) = LOWER([t1].[Email]))
    )) OR (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [ClientUsers] AS [t7]
    INNER JOIN [Clients] AS [t8] ON [t7].[ClientId] = ([t8].[Id])
    WHERE ([t7].[Email] = LOWER([t1].[Email])) AND ([t8].[ClientTypeId] = @p8)
    ))))) AND ([t0].[ClientTypeId] = @p9)
```

The query works but takes 5 minutes to run.

Comment: 54641 Clients (each Client today only has one ClientUser). 4544 of type 2 and 30287 of type 4.

Comment: I think it would be easier to help if you describe your tables and what you want to do exactly instead. Also make sure you have indexes on those columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What db collation are you using? The query can be restructured and simplified a bit, but first it might be an idea to drop all the .ToLower etc unless you are using a case sensitive collation...

**Edit:** you could try changing your query to a bunch of smaller unioned queries that leave the sql optimizer less freedom to be creative...   (many 'or' conditions in a query tend to lead to scans even if there are covering indexes).

E.g.:

```
(

from e in dc.Clients
join u in dc.ClientUsers on e.Id equals u.ClientId
join vc in dc.Clients on new { ClientTypeId = 2, e.VAT } equals new { vc.ClientTypeId, vc.VAT }
where e.ClientTypeId == 4
  && e.DeleteFlag.Equals("n")
  && e.VAT != null
  && e.VAT != "" 
select e

).Union(

from e in dc.Clients
join u in dc.ClientUsers on e.Id equals u.ClientId
join ec in dc.Clients on new { ClientTypeId = 2, e.Email } equals new { ec.ClientTypeId, ec.Email }
where e.ClientTypeId == 4
&& e.DeleteFlag.Equals("n")
&& e.Email != null
&& e.Email != ""
select e 

).Union(

from e in dc.Clients
join u in dc.ClientUsers on e.Id equals u.ClientId
join c1u in dc.ClientUsers on e.Email equals new c1u.Email
join c1c in dc.Clients on new { ClientTypeId = 2, c1u.ClientId } equals new { c1c.ClientTypeId, ClientId = c1c.Id }
where e.ClientTypeId==4
&& e.DeleteFlag.Equals("n")
&& e.Email != null
&& e.Email != ""
select e

).Union(

from e in dc.Clients
join u in dc.ClientUsers on e.Id equals u.ClientId
join c2u in dc.ClientUsers on u.Email equals c2u.Email
join c2c in dc.Clients on new { ClientTypeId = 2, c2u.ClientId } equals new { c2c.ClientTypeId, ClientId = c2c.Id }
where e.ClientTypeId==4
&& e.DeleteFlag.Equals("n")
&& u.Email != null
&& u.Email != ""
select e

)
```

Comment: SQL_SwedishStd_Pref_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: Ok. That is a case insensitive collation, so you can remove the .ToLower calls...

Comment: You are a optimizer pro! Removing the ToLower reduced execution to 3 sek. But using your Union reduced execution to near nothing!